# Vue.js props not defined in Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

The parent `app` has an object `messages`, that is being filled correctly from the server. But the `chat-room` component's props `messages` is not feeding from the parent's `messages`. What am I missing??

Here is my blade template:

```
<chat-room></chat-room>
<chat-composer v-on:messagesent="addMessage"></chat-composer>
```

Here is my `chat-room` component:

```
<template>
  <div class="chat-room">
    <chat-message v-for="message in messages" :message="message"></chat-message>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props : ['messages'],
  }
</script>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-room', require('./components/ChatRoom.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-composer', require('./components/ChatComposer.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    messages: []
  },
  methods: {
    addMessage(message) {
      this.messages.push(message);
      axios.post(base_url+'/room/1/write_message', message).then(response => { });
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(base_url+'/room/1/messages').then(response => {
      this.messages = response.data;
      console.log(this.messages); //this returns an Array[4]!
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you use your `chat-room` component?

Comment: Yeah, I got that you'd shown the contents of your `ChatRoom.vue` file. What I meant was can you show how you're using that component in you app i.e. where/how you're using `<chat-room></chat-room>`?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm using a simple html tag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the messages inside your `chat-room` component is because you're not passing them to it.

Change:

```
<chat-room></chat-room>
```

To be:

```
<chat-room :messages="messages"></chat-room>
```

Hope this helps!